# How to session maintain in spring and hibernate Framework

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, frameworks

I have small doubt about how to maintain session in Hibernate and spring framework. If using session time is defined in web.xml. That is also not use in my application. If progresses application while session is timeout. If you any one known about. Can you give any guidelines for me.

Comment: Hibernate session and Web session are two different things. Also its not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I am asking about Hibernate session.

Comment: If you are using Spring Framework that should manage the session you don't need to.

Comment: If I using application in progress. That application is session time out. How to fix that problem. you cam give sample file.

Comment: Session maintaining in separate class file.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate has nothing to do with sessions unless you are persisting them to the database.

Spring does not have much to do with sessions either, it's mostly your `Servlet` container does the job, which is, as you said - `web.xml`.

However when you are using `Spring Boot Web` with `@SpringMvcApplication` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` ( possibly made those up :) - you will use the embedded container with automatic & default Spring configuration, which you then should be looking up in [Spring Boot reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)

Comment: k fine. I want to session make in Hibernate Framework. I must be created new class file that's your suggestion I think.

Comment: Sorry but I have a hard time understanding you